# unable to get the uwp display name in from package.manifest > Application > DisplayName in Code

Tags: uwp

By using Package.Current I'm able to get Package name, package display name and publisher name , but I want to get the display name in the Application of package.manifest(image attached)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unable to get the uwp display name in from package.manifest > Application > DisplayName in Code

For your scenario you could use [`AppDiagnosticInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appdiagnosticinfo?view=winrt-19041) Class relevant APIs to get the application's display name like the following. For more info please check  this [UWP App Diagnostics](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/#vXyVYfxjW5esHEK0.97).

```
IReadOnlyList<ProcessDiagnosticInfo> processes = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForProcesses();
if (processes != null)
{
    foreach (ProcessDiagnosticInfo process in processes)
    {
        IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> diagnosticInfos = process.GetAppDiagnosticInfos();
        if (diagnosticInfos != null && diagnosticInfos.Count > 0)
        {
            AppDiagnosticInfo diagnosticInfo = diagnosticInfos.FirstOrDefault();
            var displayName = diagnosticInfo.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```